# How can I create a keyed style for a label, setting all text to UPPERCASE?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I need to create a series of keyed styles which I can apply to labels within my application.

Our design team has given me the specifics and one specification is that major headers need to be in all caps.

Instead of manage all caps text in my resource files, I'd prefer to apply a style that will do this for me.  I've read about Typography and setting on the TextBlock and the CharacterCasing property for the TextBox, but I can't find a similar property that works with labels.

What do I need to do to a style such as the one below to adjust all text to uppercase?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="HEADER">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <!-- What do I do here to convert content to UPPERCASE? -->
</Style>
```

Comment: No properties available out of the box. You can try a converter or create a custom label control to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to play with [Typography.Capitals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.capitals(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Typography.Capitals" Value="AllSmallCaps"/>
</Style>
```

it might require FontSize increase

```
<Label Style="{x:Null}" Content="QWERTY"/>
<Label Content="qwerty"/>
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="qwerty"/>
</Label>
```

result:

[image: caps]